# Sendmail not totally removed

Tags: debian, sendmail, apt-get

I can't understand why `whereis sendmail` returns me:

`sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail /usr/share/man/man1/sendmail.1.gz`

while I already remove and purge all `sendmail` packages by using :

```
apt-get remove sendmail
apt-get purge sendmail
```

Also, is that safe to remove these paths to `sendmail` elements manually ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because another package is providing a [mail transport agent](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/mail-transport-agent), for compatibility a package like Postfix will included links such that it appears the sendmail program is installed.

In the Debian Docs [7.8 What is a Virtual Package](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html)